Plot XY points along a curved line in ArcGIS Pro (for creating TIN)
I am trying to use ArcGIS Pro to replicate a process from CAD (Bentley InRoads) for creating triangulated elevation surfaces along curved lines.
In CAD, I can import a text file with XY points and plot them along the curved line preserving the offsets between the points. I can then triangulate them to create an elevation surface.
I have tried to replicate this process in ArcGIS Pro but could not find a way to plot the points along the curved (or straight) line. I used XY Table To Point and tried to align them to a curved line but couldn't find a way to preserve the offsets between the points. Is there a way to do this in ArcGIS?
Below are the screenshots of triangulated surfaces in CAD and ArcGIS
CAD:

ArcGIS:


Is this what you're after? https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/editing/create-point-features-along-a-line.htm or https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/data-management/generate-points-along-lines.htm as a geoprocessing tool. If your line has elevation that will be copied to the points, provided the Output has Z is set to true https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/environment-settings/output-has-z-values.htm for the geoprocessing or in the case of the edit tool the points feature class is Z aware.

Using text points (.XYZ) is fairly normal for CAD but in ArcGIS points from text is icky; text formats are slow to query/draw. Consider importing them into a file geodatabase and create a terrain https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/data/terrain-dataset/terrain-dataset-in-arcgis-pro.htm instead of a TIN, that will be more robust and display quicker. If you're creating TINs in ArcGIS you will already have the 3d analyst license required to create and build a terrain.

What's wrong with line itself as input for TIN ?

@MichaelStimson The text file contains some important information so unfortunately, the points generated from it can not be replaced with newly generated points using the geoprocessing tools you mentioned. I will try creating a terrain and fit it onto my curve.

@FelixIP The line does not have any elevation information. The only purpose of the line is to establish a correct curvature for the XYZ points to follow. As a workaround, I could copy and offset my lines to match the offset of the points and then align the points on these lines but this would take much longer than I would like.

Do not read further, if in 2D view your points and curve look different to picture below:

Possible workflow:

Draw long line AB
Compute chainage ('D_ALONG') of original points along this line
Place multiple point on curve and compute chainage of them to the same long line and coordinates of projected points. Table of CHAINAGE points on curve will look like this:


It represents necessary displacement links (delta X and delta Y) for your points. Note that only some of chainage and displacement lines are shown below:

Now we have 2 functions dX(D_ALONG) and dY(d_ALONG). They can be easily computed and applied to original points using their D_ALONG as argument. You might use this script to do so:
import scipy
from scipy import interpolate
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d
'get relevant layers from current map'
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
CHAINAGE,POINTS = [arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd,item)[0] for item in "CHAINAGE_POINTS","POINTS"]
'construct functions for dX and dY'
fields = ('D_ALONG','POINT_X','POINT_Y','NEAR_X','NEAR_Y')
tbl = arcpy.da.TableToNumPyArray(CHAINAGE,fields)
xCurve = interp1d(tbl['D_ALONG'],tbl['POINT_X']-tbl['NEAR_X'])
yCurve = interp1d(tbl['D_ALONG'],tbl['POINT_Y']-tbl['NEAR_Y'])
'get points info'
fields = ('OID@','D_ALONG')
DF = arcpy.da.TableToNumPyArray(POINTS,fields)
'interpolate X and Y shifts'
dxDict = dict(zip(DF["OID@"],xCurve(DF['D_ALONG'])))
dyDict = dict(zip(DF["OID@"],yCurve(DF['D_ALONG'])))
'results transfer'
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(POINTS,("OID@","dX","dY")) as cursor:
    for fid,dx,dy in cursor:
        dx,dy = dxDict[fid],dyDict[fid]
        cursor.updateRow((fid,dx,dy))

It computes 2 functions and populates fields dX,dY in original table:

To adjust points, you can use this field calculator on Shape field of (cloned!) points:
arcpy.Point( !POINT_X!+ !dX!, !POINT_Y!+ !dY!)


Biggest challenge here is automation for creation of line AB, unless this is one off exercise.
